# Update div on clicking 'submit' button (adding data to mysql) without jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, submit

I have 2 `div`s like in the image below. 1 `div` with contacts in the left with the `id='contacts-list'` and one `div` in the right with a form with the `id='contacts-details'`. 
Data from the left is added with this structure:

```
<div class='contact_entry' id='[contact_id]'>
     <span class='contact_entry_details'>[contact firstname][contact surname]</span>
</div>
```

`[contact_id]` is a value taken from MYSQL with PHP, the contact id.
`[contact firstname]` and `[contact surname]` - values taken from MYSQL

When I click submit the data is added into database using AJAX `XMLHttpRequest` object. 
How can I do that when I click submit a new `div` (with the structure above) to be added in the div with the `id='contact-details'`? (I want to to this with Javascript/AJAX, without jQuery or other framework)

To delete one is simple, I do that using PHP and for the divs I do something like this using  Javascript:

```
var elem_to_delete = document.getElementById(id);
elem_to_delete.parentNode.removeChild(elem_to_delete);
```

I want something like this, but to add data, not to delete... and I want the structure above because I have a Javascript on click event listener on every 'contact-entry' `div`, to open his details in the right, in the 'contact-details' `div`.

Picture:
http://oi58.tinypic.com/jr4ayo.jpg

Comment: There's a few ways of doing this, but you can add a hidden checkbox for each contact and add a callback in JavaScript that toggles the checked property

Comment: Which are these ways? Maybe the easiest one.